# Spring scheduler is stopping unexpectedly and starting again

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I have nearly 70 jobs which are running using spring job scheduler. 5 of them are daily jobs, 20 of them are weekly jobs and remaining will run monthly.

I configured in `applicationContext.xml` file as below

**`<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="50" />`**

Even though I configured 50 threads still I am facing the issues.

**Problem**: all daily jobs are not running daily.The jobs running details for 8 days are listed below

```
 Job_Number   No.Of times Ran
  ----------   ---------------
     1              8
     2              6
     3              4
     4              8
     5              7
```

I am unable to understand why it is happening.
I did lot of search still did not found solution.Please suggest me on this..

For testing purpose I commented my entire business logic as well(Means I scheduled just empty methods).Even in this scenario also I got the same problem.

I specified cron expressions as follows

```
monthly_cron_expression = 0 00 02 15 * ?
weekly_cron_expression = 0 00 03 ? * FRI
daily_cron_expression = 0 5 10 * * ?
```

Comment: What is the Spring version? Does any of the jobs (daily, weekly, monthly) run in parallel? Any dependency on jobs? Are you running job asynchronously?

Comment: Since you are running 70 jobs, I guess there are either jobs waiting for each other or taking a lot of time to complete (e.g. the monthly jobs), postponing the execution of other jobs. Did you configure an executer too? <task:scheduler/> is a wrapper around ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extending ThreadPoolExecutor. Even core threads are initially created and started only when new tasks arrive. Scheduled tasks don't run concurrently, even if they take longer time than repeat interval.

Comment: @NickVanderhoven - Agree, that is what I suspect too.

Comment: Have you tried Larger pool size? Like `pool-size="150"`?

Comment: Maybe you should check some of your job code, is there any deadlock or infinite loop or network request without timeout?

Comment: @Tony till I didn't tried.Can I try with large number like 200 or 300..

Comment: @NickVanderhoven I tested my jobs by commenting all the business logic aswell.So I ran jobs with out any code(empty methods),even that scenario also I got the same problem.

Comment: @Tony  I tested my jobs by commenting all the business logic aswell.So I ran jobs with out any code(empty methods),even that scenario also I got the same problem.

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma spring version is 4.x

Comment: Yes, you can try it. You can also schedule your empty job more frequent to see whether it can be scheduled. Try to log job start time and finish time.

Comment: @Tony When I scheduled empty jobs to run at everyday mid night .I got the same problem

Comment: @PSR Have you verified that your thread pool configuration is actually being applied?  Do you see 50 threads?

Comment: @punkrocker27ka how I can verify it .Can you please let me know ?

Comment: Use a profiler or just thread dump to view threads.

Comment: @Tony can I use in live environment ?

Comment: Do all 5 daily job have the same schedule? Maybe you could add the schedule of the different jobs to the question.

Comment: @dpr yes all are scheduled at same time

Comment: Can you show the schedule configuration? Is it possible that you actually configured those jobs to run not-so-daily?

Comment: @Roman using cron expression I configured

Comment: Would you mind to add the cron expressions of the different jobs (daily, weekly, monthly) to the question?

Comment: @dpr updated my question

Comment: Did you add `<task:annotation-driven executor="myScheduler" />` to your applicationContext.xml. This enables the detection of components annotated with @Async and/or @Scheduled by Spring.

Comment: How do you know how often a scheduled task is being executed? Are you writing to some kind of persistence (file, database)? Or how are you monitoring this?

Comment: @dpr yes we are saving start time and end time into database

Comment: And there is no problem with the persistence of this data or the statement you use to evaluate the execution counts? Maybe some tasks fail to insert their data due to some constraint conflicts on the DB? Just a shot in the dark, though...

Comment: @dpr even though some exception got raised in the middle we are saving end time in db.In that point of view we have taken care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128729/discussion-between-psr-and-dpr).

Comment: @PSR just to make sure, you're in the chat

Comment: @PSR any updates?

Comment: @dpr here as per the requirement we don't need transaction management.

Answer (score 0):

could you change the chron expresson for the daily job as follows and give a try
daily_cron_expression = 0 5 10 * * *