# Alternative for Thread.sleep() in java

Tags: java, multithreading, calendar, thread-sleep

I am using spring `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` in my application. One of my  methods need to be called only on Friday midnight. That method is called on server startup. So I am using the `Thread.sleep()` in the following way

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfWeek = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int daysUntilNextFriday = Calendar.FRIDAY - dayOfWeek;
if(daysUntilNextFriday < 0){
    daysUntilNextFriday = daysUntilNextFriday + 7;
}       

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, daysUntilNextFriday);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); 
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date d1 = c.getTime();

long diffTime = d1.getTime() - new Date().getTime();

Thread.sleep(diffTime);
```

In some cases it may wait for more than 1 day as well. Is there any better approach instead of using `Thread.sleep()`. I have seen in some places using `Thread.sleep()` could cause a performance issue. In my case is there any alternative to improve performance?

**Initially we scheduled nearly 50 services using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. some of the services are not starting properly .We were unable to find the exact issue from past 1 month.So we wanted to try with executor**

Please refer this [Spring scheduler is stopping unexpectedly and starting again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234549/spring-scheduler-is-stopping-unexpectedly-and-starting-again)

Comment: You should use quartz scheduler or cron for programs that need to run periodically at a specific time on a specific day.

Comment: "Improve performance"? Performance really isn't a concern if you're sleeping for a day. The bigger problem you've got is ensuring that your JVM is still running.

Comment: I would personally use a cronjob, scheduler, ExecutorService or something similar. Because Thread.sleep for one week seems like wasteful.

Comment: How about Timer()?

Comment: Actually I got the requirement to use spring executor framework

Comment: @MuratK. in executor framework  can I use cron expression.I think only with scheduler it is possible .Right ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by saying 'my method will be called in many places of application,but that need to be executed only on Friday mid night'. If your method is called, it will block the application until Friday mid night?

Comment: @Tony actually not in many places.In one place it is going to be called.Here I have to use only executor ..

Comment: I suggest you improve the question - add your constraints. Explain what framework you are using (give a link, and if a tag exists for it, add the tag). Note that Scheduler and TaskExecutor belong to the same framework.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am using spring task executor

Comment: @RealSkeptic updated my question

Comment: why not ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: @Tony Actually we scheduled nearly 50 services.So services are not starting properly .We were unable to find the issue from past  1 month.So we wanted to try with  executor

Comment: Sounds like the Tasks are waiting because the pool is exhausted. But could also be a wrong configuration or anything we can't possible know here.

Comment: @MuratK. total 50 services should have to run on every day midnight.But every day we are able to see some of the services are missing.We are saving start and end times as well , but we were unable to find the issue

Comment: @MuratK. we used <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="50" /> and increased pool size to 150 as well for some times

Comment: Try a bigger pool size than the number you are actually running. Make sure that no task runs for a day or more.

Comment: @RealSkeptic some of the tasks will run for more than one day.For example 5 tasks are running for more than 1 day, at least remaining 45 tasks should run, but which is not happening.

Comment: @RealSkeptic regarding thread count can I increase it to huge number like 400 or 500 ?

Comment: I believe you can. But perhaps you should instead use one thread for each schedule, and that thread should create 50 threads or as many as you need, and then it finishes, so that it's available the next day.

Comment: I configured my all tasks using <task:scheduled-tasks>.I didn't create any Thread my self.When using can I create a thread ?

Comment: @RealSkeptic how to configure using a single Thread

Answer (score 4):

You can use a ScheduledExecutorService to schedule the work to take place after certain amount of time.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.schedule(() -> {
            /*
             * define work to be done inside this lambda
             */
        }, diffTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Note: if you want the work to happen every Friday at midnight (therefore not just this coming Friday), you can modify the schedule command to happen at a set interval:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    /*
     * define work to be done inside this lambda
     */
    }, diffTime, Duration.ofDays(7).toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You said in your comments you are using Spring. So you could use a cron expression. For more details on how to use the `Scheduler` see [34. Task Execution and Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 1 ? * FRI *")
public void doSomething() {
    // do stuff
}
```

This will make it run weekly at Friday 1 am. You can use the [Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) for generating the expressions.

In your Configuration class you have to enable the scheduling via.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Murat.But is there any possibility without using scheduling i.e with executor

Comment: @PSR Why are you trying to avoid using a scheduler? It belongs to the same framework, and it's the correct tool in that framework for running tasks on a given day and time.

Comment: @PSR It makes no sense to avoid the scheduler, because it will do exactly as you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

**If you are not worried about exactness** (like caring for daylight savings shifts):

You can approximate a fixed periodicity:

7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 604800000 (a week in ms)

Then you can call the executor like this:

```
Runnable task = <your task extending Runnable>    
long difftime = <time to next friday>;
long week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, difftime, week, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This will cause the executor to first wait for the difftime-delay, then execute the task with the specified periodicity.

**If you *are* worried about exactness**:
Then instead call:

```
executor.schedule(task, difftime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

which will only execute your task once. In your task - call a method that will re-schedule the task for the next execution with a newly calculated difftime.

Answer (score 0):

As advised by other users use `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, it is provided by Spring framework and resides in the same package `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` does.

Another alternative is `ScheduledExecutorService`, which is provided by Core Java and has similar functionality.

Both services allow you to configure thread pool size (500 or whatever you want). But remember, if you your workers trigger at different time frames you can reuse smaller amount of threads, especially if they do not run for a long period of time.

Additionally make sure you intercept all exceptions which occur in your workers to avoid unexpected failures you observe.

There two common patterns to accomplish this:

1. Surround worker code in try / catch block:

   ```
   public void run() {
       try {
           doRun();
       } catch (Throwable t) {
           LOG.error("exception occurred in worker", t);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to intercept and log failures in all threads where exceptions were not intercepted:

   ```
   public class DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {
       static {
           if (Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() == null) {
               Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler());
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
           if (!(e instanceof ThreadDeath)) {
               LOG.error("uncaught exception occurred in thread " + t.getName(), e);
           }
       }
   }
   ```